Drawing Feynman diagrams
I am working on my MSc thesis on Quantum Electrodynamics. I have to draw some Feynman diagrams for Compton scattering and similar processes, for which I want to use Microsoft Visio. I am having a hard time figuring out how to draw the photon lines (a wavy line) in Visio. Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated. One can also recommend me a better software. Please note that I am not trying to promote Microsoft products.

See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86588/package-for-typesetting-feynman-diagrams-efficiency-of-feynmp-and-tikz

Seriously, as a physicist, you need to learn LaTeX.

I already know LaTeX. I asked here because I thought people might know of some really great application.

After much research, I found one application that does this in a way that I actually wanted. It is called FeynGame.jar, a Java application that requires JDK installed in the system.
